# How to use a Java8 lambda to sort a stream in reverse order?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm using java lambda to sort a list.

how can I sort it in a reverse way?

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894818/how-to-sort-arraylistlong-in-java-in-decreasing-order), but I want to use java 8 lambda.

Here is my code (I used * -1) as a hack

```
Arrays.asList(files).stream()
    .filter(file -> isNameLikeBaseLine(file, baseLineFile.getName()))
    .sorted(new Comparator<File>() {
        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            int answer;
            if (o1.lastModified() == o2.lastModified()) {
                answer = 0;
            } else if (o1.lastModified() > o2.lastModified()) {
                answer = 1;
            } else {
                answer = -1;
            }
            return -1 * answer;
        }
    })
    .skip(numOfNewestToLeave)
    .forEach(item -> item.delete());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse order"? If you replace `-1 * answer` with `answer`, the order will change to reverse of what it was with `-1 * ...`.

Comment: Beware! All of your code suggests that you want to use [`forEachOrdered`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-) instead of [`forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-)

Comment: why is that? can you explain?

Comment: Follow the links. Simply said, `forEachOrdered`, as the name suggests, cares about encounter order which is relevant as you want to skip a certain number of *newest* files which relies on the “sorted by modification time” *order*.

Comment: I don't fully get it. as the `forEach` in my example happens after the `skip`. meaning after my filter, I don't care about the order

Comment: A bit late, I want to acknowledge that your understanding of how `sort`→`skip`→(unordered)`forEach` should work, is correct and that it is indeed implemented to work this way in today’s JREs, but back in 2015, when the previous comments were made, it was indeed an issue (as you may read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28259636/2711488)).

Answer (score 300, accepted):

You can adapt the solution you linked in [How to sort ArrayList<Long> in Java in decreasing order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894818/how-to-sort-arraylistlong-in-java-in-decreasing-order) by wrapping it in a lambda:

`.sorted((f1, f2) -> Long.compare(f2.lastModified(), f1.lastModified())`

note that *f2* is the first argument of `Long.compare`, not the second, so the result will be reversed.

Comment: … or `Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified).reversed()`

Comment: @Holger Stream of String, and having `comparingLong(v->Long.valueOf(v)).reversed()` throws compiling error: `java.lang.valueOf(java.lang.String) cannot be used on java.lang.valueOf(java.lang.Object)`. Why?

Comment: @Tiina: see [Comparator.reversed() does not compile using lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25172595/2711488). You may try `comparingLong(Long::valueOf).reversed()` instead. Or `Collections.reverseOrder(comparingLong(v->Long.valueOf(v)))`

Comment: @Holger thanks for the link. But the Stuart "not entirely sure why". I was confused when i saw both methods refer `T` instead of `Object`, meaning the object type should not be lost. But actually it is. That is what I am confused about.

Comment: @Tiina: Well, Brian Goetz’ comment explains the difference. I was surprised too that Stuart didn’t know that “target typing” doesn’t work through chained invocations, but on the other hand, that was 2014. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31383947/2711488) for more details.

Comment: @Holger if chained style would cause type lose, how can we write builder pattern?

Comment: @Tiina: it’s the back-propagation of the *target type* which doesn’t work. If the initial expression of your chain has a stand-alone type, it works through the chain like it did before Java 8. As you can see with the comparator example, using a method reference, i.e. `comparingLong(Long::valueOf).reversed()` works, likewise an explicitly-typed lambda expression works `comparingLong((String v) -> Long.valueOf(v)).reversed()` works. Also `Stream.of("foo").mapToInt(s->s.length()).sum()` works, as the `"foo"` provides the stand-alone type whereas `Stream.of().mapToInt(s-> s.length()).sum()` fails.

Comment: Downvoted because didn't mention `reversed()` (see comments and other solutions). Happy to turn this into an upvote if corrected.

Comment: But isn't 1. sorting 2. reversing more ineffective then 1. inverted sort ?! My only concern are null values

Answer (score 291):

If your stream elements implement `Comparable` then the solution becomes simpler:

```
 ...stream()
 .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

Comment: or `...stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder())`

Comment: For the most recent element in a collection comparing by date
`.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Clazz::getDate))`

Comment: What if the elements are not ```Comparable```. ```Collections.reverse``` does not have such a restriction.

Answer (score 85):

Use

```
Comparator<File> comparator = Comparator.comparing(File::lastModified); 
Collections.sort(list, comparator.reversed());
```

Then

```
.forEach(item -> item.delete());
```

Comment: Well, he asked about streams, but I like your answer nonetheless.

Comment: This is not "functional" way of doing it... it's got side affects!!

Answer (score 62):

You can use a method reference:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Arrays.asList(files).stream()
    .filter(file -> isNameLikeBaseLine(file, baseLineFile.getName()))
    .sorted(comparing(File::lastModified).reversed())
    .skip(numOfNewestToLeave)
    .forEach(item -> item.delete());
```

In alternative of method reference you can use a lambda expression, so the argument of comparing become:

```
.sorted(comparing(file -> file.lastModified()).reversed());
```

Answer (score 34):

Alternative way sharing:

**ASC**

```
List<Animal> animals = this.service.findAll();
animals = animals.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Animal::getName)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**DESC**

```
List<Animal> animals = this.service.findAll();
animals = animals.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Animal::getName).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 15):

In simple, using Comparator and Collection you can sort like below in **reversal** order using **JAVA 8**

```
import java.util.Comparator;;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

Arrays.asList(files).stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(File::getLastModified).reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Make sure that, you are `override` the object with `hashCode()` and `equals` methods, otherwise the above code will not work.

Answer (score 4):

This can easily be done using Java 8 and the use of a reversed [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

I have created a list of files from a directory, which I display unsorted, sorted and reverse sorted using a simple Comparator for the sort and then calling reversed() on it to get the reversed version of that Comparator.

See code below:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SortTest {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        File directory = new File("C:/Media");
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        List<File> filesList = Arrays.asList(files);

        Comparator<File> comparator = Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified);
        Comparator<File> reverseComparator = comparator.reversed();

        List<File> forwardOrder = filesList.stream().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<File> reverseOrder = filesList.stream().sorted(reverseComparator).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("*** Unsorted ***");
        filesList.forEach(SortTest::processFile);

        System.out.println("*** Sort ***");
        forwardOrder.forEach(SortTest::processFile);

        System.out.println("*** Reverse Sort ***");
        reverseOrder.forEach(SortTest::processFile);
    }

    private static void processFile(File file) {
        try {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath() + " - " + new Date(file.lastModified()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sort file list with java 8 Collections

Example how to use Collections and Comparator Java 8 to sort a File list.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class ShortFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        fileList.add(new File("infoSE-201904270100.txt"));
        fileList.add(new File("infoSE-201904280301.txt"));
        fileList.add(new File("infoSE-201904280101.txt"));
        fileList.add(new File("infoSE-201904270101.txt"));

        fileList.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getName()));
        Collections.sort(fileList, Comparator.comparing(File::getName).reversed());
        System.out.println("===========================================");
        fileList.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getName()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of all these complications, this simple step should do the trick for reverse sorting using Lambda **.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())**

```
Arrays.asList(files).stream()
.filter(file -> isNameLikeBaseLine(file, baseLineFile.getName()))
.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).skip(numOfNewestToLeave)
.forEach(item -> item.delete());
```

Comment: Its not clear, please explain it.

Answer (score 1):

For reverse sorting just change the order of x1, x2 for calling the x1.compareTo(x2) method the result will be reverse to one another

**Default order**

```
List<String> sortedByName = citiesName.stream().sorted((s1,s2)->s1.compareTo(s2)).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Sorted by Name : "+ sortedByName);
```

**Reverse Order**

```
List<String> reverseSortedByName = citiesName.stream().sorted((s1,s2)->s2.compareTo(s1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Reverse Sorted by Name : "+ reverseSortedByName );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your Comparator with your own logic like this;

```
private static final Comparator<UserResource> sortByLastLogin = (c1, c2) -> {
    if (Objects.isNull(c1.getLastLoggedin())) {
        return -1;
    } else if (Objects.isNull(c2.getLastLoggedin())) {
        return 1;
    }
    return c1.getLastLoggedin().compareTo(c2.getLastLoggedin());
};
```

And use it inside foreach as:

```
list.stream()
     .sorted(sortCredentialsByLastLogin.reversed())
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    //sort Stream in reverse oreder with using Lambda Expressrion.

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Ram","Rahul","Ravi","Vishal","Vaibhav","Rohit","Harit","Raghav","Shubhan");
    List<String> sortedListLambda = list.stream().sorted((x,y)->y.compareTo(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(sortedListLambda);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to sort by Object's date type property then

```
public class Visit implements Serializable, Comparable<Visit>{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4976278839883192037L;

private Date dos;

public Date getDos() {
    return dos;
}

public void setDos(Date dos) {
    this.dos = dos;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Visit visit) {
    return this.getDos().compareTo(visit.getDos());
}
```

}

```
List<Visit> visits = getResults();//Method making the list
Collections.sort(visits, Collections.reverseOrder());//Reverser order
```