# When does Java require explicit type parameters?

Tags: java, java-8

Given:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Testcase
{
    public static <T, K, V> MapCollectorBuilder<T, K, V>
        toImmutableMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
            Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static final class MapCollectorBuilder<T, K, V>
    {
        public Collector<T, ?, ImmutableMap<K, V>> build()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableMap<K, V>> toImmutableMap2(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void main(String[] args)
    {
        Function<String, String> keyMapper = i -> i;
        Function<String, Integer> valueMapper = Integer::valueOf;

        ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map1 = Stream.of("1", "2", "3")
            .collect(Testcase.toImmutableMap(keyMapper, valueMapper).build());

        ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map2 = Stream.of("1", "2", "3")
            .collect(Testcase.toImmutableMap(i -> i, Integer::valueOf).build());

        ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map3 = Stream.of("1", "2", "3")
            .collect(Testcase.toImmutableMap2(i -> i, Integer::valueOf));
    }
}
```

The statements involving `map1` and `map3` compile fine, but `map2` fails with:

```
Testcase.java:[41,57] incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,K,V
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      no suitable method found for valueOf(java.lang.Object)
          method java.lang.Integer.valueOf(java.lang.String) is not applicable
            (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
          method java.lang.Integer.valueOf(int) is not applicable
            (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to int))
```

The compiler error can be solved by providing explicit type parameters `<String, String, Integer>`.

1. When does Java 8 require explicit type parameters? Meaning, is there a known pattern that breaks type inference?
2. Can `toImmutableMap()` and `MapCollectorBuilder` be changed to avoid explicit type parameters without losing the use of a Builder for configuring the Collector?

**UPDATE**:

3. Why does the statement involving `map3` work? How does it differ from the statement involving `map2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question “Meaning, is there a known pattern that breaks type inference?” shortly: of course, there is a pattern, moreover there is a [huge specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) for the entire behavior of the Java programming language.

But the chapters regarding type inference and method invocation types are really exhaustive and hard to understand. This is best illustrated by the fact that in the case of unexpected behavior, often large discussions about the expected behavior according to the specification occur.

But there are some points explainable and rememberable for a programmer.

There are two ways how to infer the type parameters, by the arguments passed to a method or parts from which an expression is composed or by the *target type* of an expression, that is, the expected type for a parameter of an invocation, the variable which is assigned or the return type of a method in case of a return statement.

The target type can get propagated through nested method invocations like in

```
TargetType x=foo(bar(/*target type can be used*/));
```

or in a conditional like

```
TargetType x=condition? foo(/*target type can be used*/): foo(/*target type can be used*/);
```

but *not* in case of a chained invocation as in

```
TargetType x=foo(/*target type can NOT be used*/).foo();
```

---

Now to your examples:

```
ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map1 = Stream.of("1", "2", "3").collect( expression );
```

Here, the `Stream.of(…)` and `.collect(…)` are *chained*, therefore the target type cannot be used to determine the stream type of the `of` invocation but the arguments provided to that method are sufficient to infer the type `Stream<String>`. The `collect` method provides the result that gets assigned to `map1`, so both, the stream type `Stream<String>`*and* the target type `ImmutableMap<String, Integer>` are known and can be used for the type inference for the *expression*. Onto the expressions:

- `Testcase.toImmutableMap(keyMapper, valueMapper).build()` this is a chained invocation, so the target type is known for `build()` but not for `toImmutableMap`. However, the arguments to `toImmutableMap` are local variables which have a known exact type, therefore the type inference can use them to infer the result type of `toImmutableMap` and check whether it matches the expectations for `.build()`
- `Testcase.toImmutableMap(i -> i, Integer::valueOf).build()` this is again a chained invocation but now the argument `i - > i` has an incomplete type and suffers from the absence of the target type. The attempt to guess a type for `i -> i` without knowledge about the target type fails.
- `Testcase.toImmutableMap2(i -> i, Integer::valueOf)` this is *not* a chained invocation, therefore the target type is available for the `toImmutableMap2` call (in respect to the `collect` call, it’s a nested invocation). Therefore, the target type of `toImmutableMap2` allows to infer target types for the parameters, hence for the `i -> i` lambda expression. With a proper target type, the correct functional signature can be inferred.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, chained invocation is allowed to pass information forward but not backward in the chain. Given `TargetType x = A.of(ArgumentType).buildB().buildC()`, we are able to pass `ArgumentType` forward, from `A` to `C` but we are not able to pass `TargetType` backward, from `C` to `A`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

The target type of a lambda expression is determined entirely from context, [as discussed in the Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing).  Therefore, lambdas do not contribute to type parameter inference; instead, they *rely* on it.  Method references "*are* compact, easy-to-read *lambda expressions* for methods that already have a name" (Oracle Java Tutorial; emphasis added), so the there is no distinction there that would color type analysis differently when they are involved.

When you assign your lambda / method reference to a variable, that variable's type provides the context for inferring type parameters.  When you pass them directly to a generic method, however, you need some other mechanism to infer their types.  In some cases, other arguments to the method might serve that purpose.  In your particular case, it looks like you probably need explicit type arguments:

```
ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map2 = Stream.of("1", "2", "3").collect(
        Testcase.<String, String, Integer>toImmutableMap(i -> i, Integer::valueOf).build());
```

**Update**

With respect to the updated question, it looks like Java can infer types correctly in the `map3` case in part because the determination is not complicated by invocation of the `MapCollectorBuilder.build()` method.  Without `build()`, the type of `map3` provides the context to determine the first type argument of `Stream.collect()`, which gives both `K` and `V`.  Type parameter `T` can be inferred from the (inferred) type of the `Stream`.

With `build()` involved, however, I think Java is separating the question of inferring the type parameters for generic method `toImmutableMap()` from the question of the type of the return value of invoking `build()` on its return value.  In other words, it wants determine the type of the object returned by `toImmutableMap()` before it considers the type of the value obtained by invoking a method on that value.

Comment: I think the problem is `.collect(Testcase.toImmutableMap(**i -> i**, Integer::valueOf)`. Generic types do not propagate to other classes. In this case, Java does not know, that `i` can only be of type `String` and therefore assumes `Object`. In the first case, you have a `Function<String, String>` instance. This instance carries the information, that it maps from `String` to `String` and Java can correctly infer the type.

Comment: @Turing85, as far as I can determine, the problem is with *both* lambdas, including the one that is also a method reference.  With respect to `i -> i` in particular, though, you have simply restated what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: If the method reference could be used to infer type arguments then Java should be able to infer `T` and `V` from it, but the compiler complains that none of `T`, `K`, or `V` can be inferred.

Comment: Thank you. I've added a related statement (`map3`) that I was expecting to trigger a compiler error, but does not. Can you please update your answer to address this?

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to fix this. You can give a hint to compiler explicitly specifying the argument type for identity lambda:

```
ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map2 = Stream.of("1", "2", "3")
    .collect(Testcase.toImmutableMap((String i) -> i, Integer::valueOf).build());
```

Compiles fine in Javac 1.8.0_25 and ECJ 3.10.2.

Comment: The interesting thing you just proved is that type inference is only failing for `<T>`. Once we supply an explicit type, the remaining variables get inferred correctly.