# sort HashMap in reverse?

Tags: java, sorting, generics, hashmap, comparator

So I came across this method which is able to sort HashMaps by value.

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue(Map<K, V> map) {
        return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (e1, e2) -> e1,
                        LinkedHashMap::new
                        ));
    }
```

I want to use the `reversed()` method on the `Comparator` but I can't seem to find the right place to put it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28607267/616460

Comment: @JornVernee that doesn't work

Comment: "doesn't work"? "Doesn't work" how?

Comment: @LewBloch .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed()) does not compile. Mureinik's solution works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `reversed()` method should be called on the `Comparator` returned by `comparingByValue()`. Java's type inference breaks down here, unfortunately, so you'll have to specify the generic types:

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue
    (Map<K, V> map) {

    return map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<K, V> comparingByValue().reversed())
            // Type here -----^ reversed() here -------^
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (e1, e2) -> e1,
                    LinkedHashMap::new
            ));
}
```

Comment: @BenArnao Which is exactly why it's generally a good idea to include what you've tried in your question as well as clear descriptions of why what you tried hasn't worked.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i needed. I tried using reversed() at that place but it didn't work because i had to specify the type.