# Comparator parameters

Tags: java, comparator

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607191/how-to-use-a-java8-lambda-to-sort-a-stream-in-reverse-order) post about reversing order with lambdas, but one thing that's confused me even with traditional Comparator implementations (or anonymous inner classes) is: why does comparing the second argument with the first argument reverse the order?

For example:

```
public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    return o2.compareTo(o1);
}
```

In the above snippet, integers will be sorted in reverse order. However, `o1.compareTo(o2)` results in a normal order. Why does switching the order of comparison work, and why does this extend to other custom comparators?

Comment: What is the difference between `a < b` and `b < a`? You're reversing the order. That's what it does.

Comment: But without knowing if ```a > b```, there's no difference.

Comment: `b < a` is synonymous with `a > b`.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that when comparing `a to b` comparator returns `1, 0, and -1` for `a > b, a == b and a < b`, respectively.

To reverse the order you want `-1, 0, and 1` as a result of the comparisons. But to get that to happen you actually must reverse the inequalities and compare `b to a`.