# How to sort an ArrayList<String> Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I am populating an ArrayList with 2 items from a sql database: An ID and a Date (stored as a string).
I want to sort the ArrayList by the Date, and then loop over the sorted array to get back from the database the rest of the information.

Can I achieve this using ArrayList, and if so, HOW? OR

I need to create and populate a different type of Array, if so, what and how to sort it?

I will need to loop over the sorted array to get the rest of the information per record from the database.

I have the following code:

```
final ArrayList<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

while (i<=numRows){
      artID = helper.getTextFromTable(ArticlesTable, i, "achievementID");
      Date = helper.getTextFromTable(ArticlesTable, i, "date");
      firstList.add(artID);
      firstList.add(Date);              
      i= i+1;
    }
```

I have searched but have not found the answer.
Thanks very much.

Comment: check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894818/how-to-sort-arraylistlong-in-java-in-decreasing-order   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894818/how-to-sort-arraylistlong-in-java-in-decreasing-order

Comment: It looks like you should define a class that has fields for achievementID and date, and populate your list with instances of that.

Comment: @MD - Thank you, I have seen the other SO questions, but they don't provide the answers I need. I am asking if my current ArrayList can be used, which I think it can't, and if so, what should I use. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following one

```
 Collections.sort(your_array_list);
```

> sort
>
> - Sorts the specified list in ascending natural order. The algorithm is stable which means equal elements don't get reordered.

Comment: Why you answered such a questions? better to flag it as duplicate becoz already lots of answers available in SO.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I don't think my original Array is set up correct to allow for sorting. So when I finish populating the array i have  '[E3, 13-May-2015, E4, 14-May-2015]'; and after the line of code above I get the following: '[13-May-2015, 14-May-2015, E3, E4]

Comment: It also doesn't solve the problem (see @SteveChaloner's comment)